# Left join returning three null records in addition to the desired results?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007, left-join

In an attempt to troubleshoot a query that I am working on, I have removed the extraneous SQL and am left with the bare bones `Left Join` between two tables, `[TableH]` and `[TableD]` for convention.
`[TableH]` contains `A` as a unique identifier among a number of other fields, and `[TableD]` contains multiple records with the same values of `A`. Here is a visual example:

```
TableH  
    A    |    B
111112   | Red
111113   | Red
111114   | Red
111115   | Blue
111116   | White

TableD  
    A    |    B    |   C..
111112   |  100    |  ....
111112   |  87     |  ....
111112   |  12     |  ....
111113   |  124    |  ....
111114   |  210    |  ....
```

When I run the following query

```
SELECT 
    TD.*
FROM
    TableH AS TH
        LEFT JOIN 
        TableD AS TD
        ON TH.A = TD.A
```

I get the expected result of all ~500,000 entries from TableD, but I also get three additional rows in the results which are blank/NULL all the way across.

```
Query Results
    A    |    B    |   C..
         |         |  ....
         |         |  ....
         |         |  ....
111112   |  100    |  ....
111112   |  87     |  ....
111112   |  12     |  ....
111113   |  124    |  ....
111114   |  210    |  ....
```

What is the cause of the additional 3 rows?

Comment: That's the `left join`. If there is no match in the second table for a line in the first one, the missing columns are filled with `null`.

Comment: It clearly describes this behavior in the documentation.

Comment: I am aware of how `LEFT JOIN` works, as I stated in the reply to Amit. Each `TableH.A` has between one and many matches in `TableD.A`, and there aren't any values exclusive to one of the tables.

Comment: Use `SELECT TH.A, TD.*  FROM TableH AS TH LEFT JOIN TableD AS TD ON TH.A = TD.A WHERE TD.A Is Null;` to see which `TH.A` values Access can't find in `TableD`

Answer (score 2):

That's how left join works. It creates 1 or more row(s) for each row in the left table (`TableH`), and for each of these, if there is a match in the right table (`TableD`) it fills the values from that table, and otherwise fill with NULLs.

In your case, all the unmatched ID's have rows with NULL values in `TD`s columns, and when you `SELECT TD.*` you see these NULLs.

Comment: I'm aware of how the different `JOIN` statements work, which is why it's confusing that I'm getting three NULL rows. Each `TableH.A` has between one and many matches in `TableD.A`, and there aren't any values exclusive to one of the tables.

Answer (score 1):

This query:

```
SELECT TD.*
FROM TableH AS TH LEFT JOIN 
     TableD AS TD
     ON TH.A = TD.A;
```

Returns all rows in `TableH`, not `TableD`, whether or not there is a match in `TableD`.  So, the three rows with `NULL`s are rows in `TableH` that have no rows in `TableD`.

You probably intend:

```
SELECT TD.*
FROM TableD TD LEFT JOIN 
     TableH TH
     ON TH.A = TD.A;
```

Answer (score -1):

You should change your query to below, bringing `TableD` to `FROM` clause since you said `SELECT TD.*`

```
SELECT 
    TD.*
FROM TableD AS TD    
        LEFT JOIN 
        TableH AS TH ON TH.A = TD.A;
```